# SharePoint Server Farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, server-farm

I'm a new SharePoint. Now I met a very difficult problem.

There is a SharePoint 2010 installed in my company. But I can not distinguish it is independent of the server or the entire farm. Can you give me some ideas to let me find it ?

I want to add a web server in an existing farm. And I heard independent server can not be added. I need to identify it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have administrative access to the server's OS? Are you able to log on via RDP or at the console?

Comment: @RobertKaucher Sorry , I'm not sure what you mean. I have the highest authority of the account , and I can access every where. Can you tell me some details which I should do? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to be able to access the central admin web site. If you don't know the URL and port and you can log on to the server, you will find an icon for central administration under all programs.

If you are able to access the site go to **System Settings** > **Manage servers in the farm**

[image]

in the Servers in Farm page you should be able to determine where the SQL Server is from `Configuration database server`. If the instance name is `[name of server]\SQLExpress` it is very probable that this is a single server installation. But we still cannot be totally sure. If it is *anything* else, *even just the name of the current server*, then you are safe and it's a Farm installation.

Just to be clear, a Farm installation ***can all be done on one server*** and the databases can be moved later and additional servers can also be added later. But a "single server" installation automatically uses SQLExress. The term "single server" is misleading.

***If it is not*** documented some where, you will need to reset the Farm Passphrase. You do that by using the SharePoint PowerShell console with these commands:

```
$passphrase = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Your passphase text goes here' -asPlainText –Force
Set-SPPassPhrase -PassPhrase $passphrase -Confirm
```

Make sure you document it so that it can be found later. You will need this to join another server. Try joining the new server to the farm using the farm passphrase.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.According to your description, I found is probably a single server.But I have another qusetion . Is not only a single server will put the database on the same server? I mean If it was installed a server farm in the beginning. The database must be installed on other servers?

Comment: I just want to find a way which don't need to  change any settings to distinguish its .

Comment: No, the database server can still be the same server even in a server farm configuration.

Comment: What is shown on the page for `Configuration database server`?

Comment: The default installation sharepoint server named 'server10', The 'Configuration database server' named server10 too. But on the page I can see other server which is Not Configed .

Comment: If it does **not** contain SQLExpress then this is a Server Farm installation. A single server install would be `server10\SQLExpress`.

Comment: Just to be clear, a Farm installation can all be done on one server and the databases can be moved later. Additional servers can also be added later. But in single server installation automatically uses `SQLExress`.

Comment: So it is. Thank you very much generous answer. I have learned more about it now.